# Can module variables in rails' models be accessed in initializers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a file in `config/initializers` that needs to access certain constants, most secret. I created a `module` in `app/models` and wanted to call the constant in initializers as `MODULE.something` . But then it occurred me that probably this data won't be accessed in initializers. What should I do exactly? How can I assure that some variables (that should be accessed everywhere) will get up first things first, even before the initializer?

For the record, I'm referring to application data just as twitter/facebook api secret key

Comment: Put the data in [secrets.yml](https://richonrails.com/articles/the-rails-4-1-secrets-yml-file).

Comment: Initializers are run in order, too. Secret stuff should be secret, as Sergio states. Where to put other types of data depends on the nature of the data, IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, your API keys are secret and should not be stored in your code base. Assuming that the module loads the keys securely, I'd recommend you store the module in the `lib/modules` directory. You can then load it in an initializer in the `config/initializers` directory. Rails executes initializers in alphabetical order before loading models and other application files, so you can ensure this module is loaded first by naming the initializer something with prepended numbers, e.g. `01_secure_key_module.rb`.

Comment: **I have no lib/modules folder...**, should I create it?

Here's the code to my module

    `module gcons
     F_APPID = "".freeze
     F_SECRET = "".freeze
     T_APPID = "".freeze
     T_SECRET = "".freeze
    end`

How should the file be named and how can I start it in initializers?